# What are good oceanographic journals

Tags: oceanography, waves, tides, reference-request, wave-modeling

I am a developer with a oceanographic side project.
I did some ML on wave & tide data and thought of publishing it in a paper. What are some good journals to send it to? Any recommendations?

Thanks
El

Comment: If you're not familiar with the journals that cover that field, are you sure your work is novel enough to merit publication?

Comment: Haha, yeah. I would be skeptic if an outsider would be asking a similar question. Already did some research on journals myself.

Answer (score 3):

When searching for a place to publish Earth Science stuff, have a look at the two big continental scientific societies: the American Geophysical Union (AGU) and the European Geosciences Union (EGU). Both have a wide array of publications in the various fields of geosciences. AGU has [JGR Oceans](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/21699291), while EGU has [Ocean Science](https://www.ocean-science.net/) (open access). If you want to reach a broader, less specialized audience, you could also aim for [Frontiers in Earth Science](https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/earth-science#) (open access): they have a Hydrosphere section.